# Why calling async function inside <script> tags fail in Vue if no lifecycle hooks are used?

Tags: vue.js, pinia, vitest

Here is the scenario, I have a component, and inside the script tag I am calling an action

```html
<script>
if (something is true) {
    await store.doSomething()
}
</script>
```

The component fails to mount.

When I use the onMounted hook, it seems to work.

I am beginner in Vue, but my question is what is really happening when I don't use the hook? and is it always necessary to use hook when making asynchronous calls ?

Put it inside onMounted to get it to work, although ran into other test failures afterwards.

Comment: The example is likely incomplete because there's no component, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . In case you use `script setup`,  async setup only works together with Suspense. I'd recommend for a beginner to use setup function instead because `script setup` contains too much magic that isn't explained anywhere

Answer (score 1):

1. Looking at what you wrote as of right now, you should have the Options API like this

```html
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    // your code
  },
  setup() {
    // can also use setup here
  }
}
</script>
```

2. With Composition API (notice the `setup`)

```html
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  // your code
})
</script>
```

In `2.`, if you don't use `onMounted` it will be run withing the `setup` lifecycle as [shown here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram).

---

> is it always necessary to use hook when making asynchronous calls ?

Not really, but at the same time it depends on when/how you want it to run. Start by running it into `mounted` initially yep, easier and safer to understand overall.
Especially since `setup` does not re-run when re-mounted, can be quite confusing.
It also depends exactly on what is `something is true` exactly, regarding the lifecycle + state.

---

Pinia and Vitest will get their own things to think about.
I recommend reading the documentation and getting an initial grasp before proceeding.

Comment: the "something is true" basically I have a storeToRefs to get a certain value from a store. If that value exists then "something is true"